# Listing available workflow variables in a custom activity?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I am writing a custom activity to allow me to assign values to variables in a workflow from one of our LOB systems - this will have a GUI which allows you to type in the name of the workflow variable you wish to assign the value to. At the moment we are planning to use a text box so the user can type in the variable, but it would be really cool if I could populate a drop down list at run time with the available values in the workflow...

...does anyone know if this is possible? i.e. to grab a list of the variables available in the workflow that an activity has been dragged onto?

Answer (score 0):

The normal way for an activity is to use `OutArgument<T>` properties and the activity user, who creates the workflow, to hook these up using expressions.